# usbfs: process 25093 (pool) did not claim interface 0 before use

Tags: filesystems, usb, fuse, mtp

I recently got a new phone, a Moto G 2nd Gen.

I am running Debian Jessie on kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64 with `libmtp` 1.1.8-1, `libusb-1.0-0` 2:0.1.12-1, `gvfs` 1.22.2-1.

When I plug it in, it appears to be fine.

```
[169685.876370] usb 4-3: Product: XT1064
[169685.876371] usb 4-3: Manufacturer: motorola
[169685.876373] usb 4-3: SerialNumber: ZX1D5283LL
```

However, once I attempt to read or write data,

```
[170162.669923] usb 4-3: usbfs: process 25083 (mtp-detect) did not claim interface 0 before use
[170162.782789] usb 4-3: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[170162.916790] usb 4-3: usbfs: process 25083 (mtp-detect) did not claim interface 0 before use
[170162.916832] usb 4-3: usbfs: process 24862 (events) did not claim interface 0 before use
[170163.030793] usb 4-3: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[170192.375576] usb 4-3: usbfs: process 25093 (pool) did not claim interface 0 before use
[170211.841793] usb 4-3: usbfs: process 25099 (pool) did not claim interface 0 before use
[170211.841820] usb 4-3: usbfs: process 25099 (pool) did not claim interface 0 before use
[170211.842598] usb 4-3: usbfs: process 25099 (pool) did not claim interface 0 before use
[170211.842621] usb 4-3: usbfs: process 25099 (pool) did not claim interface 0 before use
[170211.843422] usb 4-3: usbfs: process 25099 (pool) did not claim interface 0 before use
[170211.843569] usb 4-3: usbfs: process 25100 (pool) did not claim interface 0 before use
[170211.851239] usb 4-3: usbfs: process 25099 (pool) did not claim interface 0 before use
[170211.851268] usb 4-3: usbfs: process 25099 (pool) did not claim interface 0 before use
[170230.072923] usb 4-3: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
```

Interestingly, I had similar issues with an Apple iPod, however I no longer am able to test that device and compare.

Comment: I had the same issue, my USB cable was bad.